# Responsabilidades da View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Por toda a internet, encontro postagens alertando sobre a responsabilidade da `View` que unicamente deveria zelar por seu nome e exibir o conteúdo.

Apesar de entender que o MVC se baseia exatamente na distribuição de funções e separação da aplicação por camadas, gostaria de entender os agravantes de utilizar a `View` para executar algumas funções simples, tais como condicionais.

Utilizando a `View` deste modo, existe alguma perda de desempenho ou vulnerabilidade de segurança?

Por exemplo, em uma das minhas aplicações eu recebo valores trafegados da URL (id) via um `ActionLink` e faço uma verificação no mesmo para uma exibição condicional de conteúdo. Essa seria uma má pratica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizar `for, foreach, if, switch,` etc. são práticas normais em *ASP.NET* em suas `Views`. Não há perca de desempenho e a parte de segurança não é afetada, o que o usuário de internet tem como resultado em seu navegador é somente só `HTML`.

Existe claro o fator senso, eu por exemplo, coloco a maioria das codificações no `Controller` e subo para as Views somente o necessário. Exemplo, se eu mando um `@model` sendo uma Lista de algum objeto (`IEnumerable`, `IList`, `List`, `ICollection`, etc.) eu sou obrigada a fazer um `for` ou `foreach` para mostrar os dados e isso é bem normal em aplicações ASP.NET MVC.

Resumindo, a maior parte da programação faça no `Controller` e nas `Views` só faça códigos triviais, como um `for`, um `if`, ou seja, o **básico**.

Comment: E quanto a Where em listas? O certo é não existir isso em View, né?

Comment: Isso @DiegoZanardo não é boa prática, já mande a informação final e na Views coisas básicas!

Answer (score 3):

De forma alguma seria má prática o trabalho da View é exatamente esse, exibir os dados e esses tipos de validações, que são mais do que normais, são necessárias.

Quanto a questão de segurança não, pois a página é escrita de uma vez só pelo Response e não fornece acesso algum ao usuário.